# Importing Python 3 Libraries Issue "ImportError: No module named..."

Tags: raspbian, python, modules

I am trying to use a module I have downloaded in Python 3, but when I call `from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l` the error `ImportError: No module named "i2clibraries"` occurs.

The folder`i2clibraries` is housed in a file called `q2w`that itself is housed in a directory called `salt`.

I added the lines

```
export QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=~/salt/q2w
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME
```

to the `.bashrc`so that I didn't have to type `. ./setup.env`every time the Pi is rebooted to run the same lines that are in the `.bashrc`.

I'm new to both Raspian and Python 3, does anyone see a major error in the way I'm attempting to link these libraries? Is there a better way to add modules to Python 3? Is what I'm doing even linking?

Comment: I think you are creating a rod for your own back when you start installing "special" libraries.  It might make a quick test easy but in the long run I would stick to using the "standard" Python smbus module (sudo apt-get install python3-smbus) and using one of the standard pieces of code to read your sensor.

Comment: Hi Joan, having spent the last five hours with the smBus library I'd like to say that you were right. It's probably for the best I learned to use this library, even though it seems fairly high-level (in the way Python is higher than assembly).

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be worth it. I'm sure the majority of Python code you find for I2C sensors will be using the smbus module.

Comment: Please refrain from putting meta information such as "solved" or "not relevant" in the title. If it really is not relevant it should be closed or deleted. Your update on the other hand suggests that there is a reasonable answer to the question and that might as well be posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was never solved, but using the smBus python library ended up making the need for the quick2wire library irrelevant.

---

<sup>Per OP's edit to the question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting the i2clibraries folder to your working directory. I.e : if your code is in desktop/myfolder , shift the library folder to "myfolder" . I know there is some other elegant ways of fixing this (adding paths) but this is the quickest and easiest fix.